# Selection contains unresolved reference

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I got a class that extends from TextField. I inserted the control manually into the fxml file and included an import statement. Now I can't see the controls in the Scene Builder version 2.0. Instead I get a message stating: "Selection contains unresolved reference". How would I go about and resolve them?

**Edit:**

I think I was not clear in stating where my problem lies. It seems to me that I should be able to set the classpath that points to the class of my custom control. Some websites like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/library-panel.htm) one tell me to choose a menu entry called *Resolve Unknown Types*. Since this menu entry **does not exist** in my version of Scene Builder I thought that there must exist some new mechanism which resolves these kind of issues. That's the reason why I was so vague in my question. In hindsight that might have not been a good idea.

**FocusedTextField.java:**

```
package de.foo.bar.gui;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class FocusedTextField extends TextField{

    public void setStringProperty(StringProperty stringProperty){
        focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
                                       stringProperty.setValue(getText()));
    }
}
```

Excerpt from **FooDialog.fxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.foo.bar.gui.*?>    
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane>
    <children>                        
        <FocusedTextField fx:id="fooField" />
        <FocusedTextField fx:id="barField" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Which scene builder are you using? Did you import the Jar containing the new Control inside the Scene Builder?

Comment: I am using Scene Builder 2.0 and I defined the custom control in the project I want to use it in, so there is no external jar to import.

Comment: Even if it is inside the project, Scene Builder is an external tool, which needs to know about the new Custom control which you have defined.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha edited my question to clarify things. I was too vague with my problem statement.

Comment: Can you create a controller class for your FXML and import your FocusedTextField class in the code for it?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem when i copied header section xml to another fxml layout file.
but when i copied along with import statements it's cleared..
now scene builder displays the layout file after it's been edited by another source.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the assignment of the classpath in the fxml for the Scene Builder to pick up the Class file. If you are using Eclipse, then the classpath will point to your `bin` directory.

**FooDialog.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import custom.*?>
<?import custom.FocusedTextField?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../bin?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <FocusedTextField fx:id="fooField" />
    <FocusedTextField fx:id="barField" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FocusedTextField.java**

```
package custom;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class FocusedTextField extends TextField {

    public void setStringProperty(final StringProperty stringProperty) {
        focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                    Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                stringProperty
                .setValue(getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your case, you can use the package that you want. Just keep in mind that classpath is a relative path, so if your fxml is in src/de/foo/bar/gui/FooDialog.fxml. Then the classpath will be

```
<?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../../bin?>
```

Comment: I am using IntelliJ therefore I was going with `<?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../../target/classes?>` but that doesn't fix it. I also tried to add or remove `../` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the  same problem when I copied XML from one  xml file to another, For me I resolved it by just by closing and reopening scene builder. Hope this helps someone.